# akka stream design pattern for files consumption

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have a problem where I am asked to use akka streams to design a search API to look for data into several related .tsv files. 
For ex you have 2 files: 
*movies.tsv (id, title)* 
*actors.tsv (name, movieIds)* 
Say you want to create an endpoint listing all the actors that played in one movie just specifying the name 
`def principalsForMovieName(name: String): Source[Actor, _]` 
you would have to read the first file to get all the movie ids containing the input name and then process the second file to list the related actors. 
I thought I could to that by piping 2 Sources (first movies then actors) together but that does not appear like something common with akka reactive streams.
I might have missed something in the whole stream concept I guess. Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: First off all, if you are asked to return a source as a result ( if you really have to return a Source[Actor, _] ) you need to deploy your own graph shape, you can learn more [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html), but if you don't necessarily need to return a source as the result, you can use 2 flows, the first one gives you back the `id`s of the movies based on the movie names you pass to it, the second one should give you back the actors participated in that movie, so for example you would have a list of actors.

Comment: yes indeed the signature is given so I have to look into the Graph documentation I guess. To start with one source and get to the final one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is workable, albeit inefficient if multiple movies happen to share a title:

- read a stream of lines from `movies.tsv`
- filter the stream for titles matching the name of the movie and `map` to the movie IDs
- for each movie ID, emit a stream of lines from `actors.tsv` (`flatMapConcat` is probably the stream operator of interest here)
- filter the stream for records matching that movie ID
- `map` each record to the actor name

The inefficiency arises from repeatedly re-reading and scanning `actors.tsv`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, indeed that seems so inefficient that I thought there is a way to combine streams but maybe I am missing something there.
Maybe materializing the first filtered movies data into a list could be a better option though inefficient too in case of huge list...

Comment: A reasonable model for this domain would probably, it should be noted, not have multiple movies with the same title, in which case the inefficiency if there's a collision is worth it.

Comment: flatMapConcat does indeed the trick of providing the possibility to chain Sources together.

Comment: If the inefficiency proves to be a problem (because of multiple movies with the same title), I'd go with pre-loading the movie -> film actor mapping into persistent (probably cluster sharded) actors from `actors.tsv` and replacing the `flatMapConcat` onwards with a `mapAsync` that does an ask of the mapping actor.

Comment: indeed the computation time is about 1mn for a single query so that is quite inefficient ^^
as well because there is another file to read after actor ids are retrieved in order to get all actors info. I was doing 2 flatMapConcat in a row in the end. What akka actors implementation do you suggest?

Comment: oh sorry no problem, I'm just not sure on the implementation you refer to with akka actors. Could you just briefly describe what you meant by loading the data into an actor?
I tested loading the csv data (2gb) into a mutable HashMap even as strings it's overflowing the memory.

Comment: If you've got that amount of data, that's where cluster sharding (and persistence) comes in.  The rough outline then becomes: on instance startup, it forms a cluster with the other instances (e.g. via configured seed-nodes or akka cluster bootstrap and akka discovery), and cluster sharding is started.  I advise representing everything that can be joined on (so movies and film-actors) as a sharded actor.  Sharding in turn allows the cluster to guarantee that there's exactly one sharded actor corresponding to a given movie or film-actor in the cluster and provides a way to resolve that actor...

Comment: ...so in this way, you can spread out beyond the limits of a single instance.  By making the sharded actors persistent via event-sourcing, you allow them to be passivated: they can stop consuming memory after a period of not being used.  You can then seed them by having a cluster singleton run through the tsv files and (likely using `mapAsync` and the ask pattern) forward the row data to the appropriate actors (you can analogize this to telling each movie's actor its name and which film-actors starred in it, etc.)...

Comment: ...Then the query endpoint just needs to send a message to a movie actor to query the movie actor for the film-actors and fan out from there to the film-actor actors for the actor data (the overloading of "actor" in this context is a bit amusing :) )... `mapAsync` and the ask pattern will also be useful there.

All of this, is of course, trading memory for speed: the pure stream implementation optimizes for memory consumption, vs. speed, the mutable Map optimizes for speed, and the actor implementation lets you tweak to find a happy medium

Comment: You actually can still have passivation without event-sourcing, have a reincarnating actor rebuild itself by rescanning the TSVs: this will be slower than reading from an event store (e.g. a DB like Cassandra or Postgres)... you could even eliminate the pre-load this way.  Since the reincarnations could happen in parallel, it might even beat the pure stream in terms of cold start time.

Comment: I see the spirit, using actors as data stream providers thanks for the hint. That seems quite a bit of implementation for a technical test though. I'm surprised something quite straight forward isn't available.